# Using LINQ to fill a List<object> from xml

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

I am new to LINQ. I need to fill a `List` of the following class with information from xml.

```
class Person
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string address;
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

What is the correct way to do it in LINQ.

```
 <Company>
  ...
  ...<!--Lot of items -->
  ...
  <People>      <!--People appears only once -->
        <Instance>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>NameA</Name>
            <Address>AddressA</Address>         
        </Instance>
        <Instance>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <Name>NameB</Name>
            <Address>AddressB</Address>         
        </Instance>
        ..
        ..
 </People>
</Company>
```

I need to know the structure of LINQ expression to directly reach `<People>` tag. Also, is there any shortcuts for filling the `List', i.e map`Person`to`Instance` tag.

Answer (score 7):

I hope you know that you need to make your fields (or better make them properties) as public to able to fill the object values. You're missing public modifier in your class fields.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
List<People> people = doc.Descendants("People")
                      .FirstOrDefault()
                      .Descendants("Instance")
                      .Select(p=> new Person()
                                  {
                                      ID = p.Element("ID").Value, 
                                      Name = p.Element("Name").Value, 
                                      Address=p.Element("Address").Value
                                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Hasan Khan's answer but you will also need to make your fields public in your person class so you can instantiate them.  You can use auto-properties so something like this:

```
    class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a tutorial on how to use [Linq To XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)