# Fill List<> from XML respond

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7

My question is how can i reach

```
<xml>
 <item>
  <eventid>1</eventid>
  <eventname>Test</eventname>
  <startdate>2012-04-30 12:00:00</startdate>
  <locationid>
    <locationid>1</locationid>
    <city>Amsterdam</city>    <-----------This field
    <venuename>Java-eiland</venuename>
  </locationid>
 </item>
</xml>
```

While filling a list

```
eventInfo = (from item in events.Descendants("item")
                         select new Event
                         {
                             EventId = Convert.ToInt16(item.Element("eventid").Value),
                             EventName = item.Element("eventname").Value,
                             EventCity = ??????????
                         }).ToList();
```

I've found [Using LINQ to fill a List<object> from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846400/using-linq-to-fill-a-listobject-from-xml)
but there they don't dig deeper into the XML like i want to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just call .element on locationid to go down to the next level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
item.Element("locationid").Element("city").Value
```

Comment: Wow i feel stupid right now that i didnt try that. But Thank you very much :D